# Mysql join with existing index too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I'm trying to fetch Publishers ordered by the most used. The DB is Mysql with InnoDB

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Publisher p
JOIN SubjectTopicTheme stt ON stt.PublisherId = p.Id
JOIN LessonSubjectTopicTheme lstt ON lstt.SubjectTopicThemeId = stt.Id
GROUP BY p.Id
ORDER BY count(*);
```

- In Publishers there are 24 rows.
- In SubjectTopicTheme there are 1 400 000 rows.
- In LessonSubjectTopicTheme there are 1 357 000 rows.

There are Indexes

- In Publisher over Id (PK)
- In SubjectTopicTheme one over Id (PK) and one over PublisherId
- In LessonSubjectTopicTheme over SubjectTopicThemeId

The query runs for 4.5sec.

My main concern is that every programmer that I've encountered and most of the forum posts that I've read say that any db can handle millions of rows joins and stuff and return in in less than 0.5sec.

So am I doing something wrong? The solutions that were suggested included different types of indexes or sub queries. None helped.

[image: Visual Explain]

[image: Table Explain]

Comment: Performance depends on your query.  You have a rather complex query because there is no filtering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's the requirement. Fetch the most used. So shouldn't mysql be able to fetch million query join in less than 5secs? It's 3 tables, not 50 cross-complicated joins

Comment: If I understand this query correctly, you're reading the entire Subject and Lesson tables, so I suspect that indexing isn't the problem.  Perhaps subqueries would be faster than full table joins, but I don't have a database like this to test with.

Comment: maybe try to rewrite it with subqueries in order to remove the count(*) from the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I can advice to try this query without `ORDER BY count(*);`  Is it still slow?

Comment: One more point id MySQL configuration. What about tuning `join_buffer_size`. The larger the buffer, the more sequential access will be to the right hand table of a join operation, which can significantly improve performance. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size

Comment: What do you mean by "most used"?  Most used "topic"?  Something else?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; it sounds like the last two have something redundant.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc
If you're refering to something like this

select p.* from Publisher p 
join (
select stt.PublisherId, count(*) as Uses
from SubjectTopicTheme stt
JOIN LessonSubjectTopicTheme lstt ON lstt.SubjectTopicThemeId = stt.Id
group by stt.PublisherId) tmp on p.Id = tmp.PublisherId
order by tmp.Uses

This slowed the query by 0.5sec

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev
The Group by is the slowing part, weirdly it's slower without the order (4.4 with, 5.2 without)

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev the join_buffer_size didn't help